C++(in Fedora): error while loading shared libraries: libSFflightdata.so.0.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
When I am trying to run the C++ code in Fedora then I am getting following error:
error while loading shared libraries: libSFflightdata.so.0.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I have tried following:

sudo find / -name libSFflightdata.so: This give me the directory in which is preset and that directory is /usr/lib64/libSFflightdata.so.

Then, I run echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH which give me empty result so I run export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib64 which then assign value to the library path

Then to link then I run sudo ln -s /usr/lib64/libSFflightdata.so /usr/lib/libSFflightdata.so.0.4


But even after that same error, can anyone please help me into. Please consider that I am beginner with C++ and fedora, so if anyone have any solution please give a explaination.
Thank you.

sudo ln -s /usr/lib64/libSFflightdata.so /usr/lib/libSFflightdata.so.0.4 - you shouldn't have done that. You should have searched libSFflightdata.so.0.4 at first step. Now, your Fedora is insured, and if you did similar actions before, I am afraid, you are at a malfunctional Fedora forever.

Can you provide more information? What build command are you using? Where does libSFflightdata come from? I do not recognize this library -- and web search engine results come up empty.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
